# Relatively simple projectile motion math question

Tags: calculus

[image]

The question in the photo for part (i) I am having trouble finding inverse tan(1/3) . Would anyone be able to explain how to do it please or show the working out? 
thanks

Comment: What have you done? You simply need to verify that it works, but no one wants to do your homework for you.  Edit this post to tell us where specifically you're getting stuck.  Show us some work.

Comment: Ii cant verify that it works since taninverse (1/3) doesnt equal pi/4. So im not sure where to start.

Comment: im also unsure about the equation for the displacement of y. I thought there would be a constant of +60 on the end to account for height.

Comment: So you verified that pi/4 works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Let at time "t", it hits the ground.

Then the horizontal distance $$120 = 20\sqrt{2}tcos\alpha$$

So you get $$t = \frac{120}{20\sqrt{2}cos\alpha}$$

Substituting the value of t in the below equation, you get

Now $ y = -60 = 120 tan\alpha - 90 sec^{2}\alpha$

Thus, Rearranging and using the identity  $sec^{2}\alpha = 1+tan^{2}\alpha$

we get $$ 3tan^{2}\alpha - 4tan\alpha +1 =0$$

When you solve the quadratic we get $tan\alpha = \frac{1}{3}\text {or}  1$

$tan\alpha = 1$ gives

$ \alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$

or

$ \alpha = tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$

Part II

Substitute the value of cos\alpha in the equation of t and find the time

Part III

Take derivatives of the x and y with respect to t and substitute the value of t =6 in both the equations and find the magnitude to get the speed $\sqrt{(x')^{2} + (y')^{2}}$.

Comment: You are welcome!